# Is it possible to call editActionsForRowAt of UITableview manually?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my project, there is a requirement to call `editActionsForRowAt` of a `UITableView` on a button action. So that on clicking that button, `tableview` swipes left.

My editActionsForRowAt code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {


    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit".localized) {[weak self] (rowAction, indexPath) in

        // Perform edit action here
    }

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete".localized) {[weak self] (rowAction, indexPath) in
         // Perform delete action here
    }

    return [deleteAction,editAction]
}
```

I do not know whether it is possible or not? I have searched a lot but did not find any solution. Please suggest is it possible or not? If yes, then how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CustomCellDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier") as? CustomCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    cell.indexPath = indexPath
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    return nil
}

func delete(for cell: CustomCell) {
    let indexPath = cell.indexPath
    print("doing action for cell at: \(indexPath!.row)")
    // your implementation for action
    // maybe delete a cell or whatever?
    cell.hideDeleteActions()

}

}

protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
func delete(for cell: CustomCell)
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?
var indexPath: IndexPath!

@IBOutlet weak var buttonAction: UIButton?
@IBOutlet weak var constBtnDeleteAction: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.constBtnDeleteAction?.constant = 0
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,
                           with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else {
        return
    }
    if self.point(inside: point, with: event) {
        self.showDeleteActions()

    }
}

func showDeleteActions() {
    self.constBtnDeleteAction?.constant = 100
    // Set it according to the button width
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

func hideDeleteActions() {
    self.constBtnDeleteAction?.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

@IBAction func cellButtonAction() {
    delegate?.delete(for: self)
}
}
```

You need to do more with storyboard like setting constraints of button which will be at the rightmost in the cell and join the outlets.

Comment: My requirement is to swipe left when button is clicked. By tblChallenge.setEditing(true, animated: true), I can delete the row but can not swipe left.

Comment: @PoojaGupta you can not perform swipe without swipe gesture. Or you need to create a custom cell with buttons and perform swipe using UIView.animation by setting custom constraints.

Comment: Can you provide a demo.

Comment: @PoojaGupta check the edited answer and let m know if any problem.

Comment: Thank you shiva_shub. Will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible by call your tableview's delegate method as below

```
@IBAction func editingstylecalled(_ sender:UIButton)
{
    let tag = sender.tag
    self.tableView(self.tableview, commit: .delete, forRowAt: IndexPath.init(row: tag, section: 0))
}
```

Please set your tableview in above code and check.

Comment: Cannot call value of non-function type 'UITableView'